# Swift Save images (screenshots) to nsuserdefaults

Tags: swift, uiimage, save, uiimagepickercontroller, nsuserdefaults

I have a program, where the user "creates" an image, and then the program takes a screenshot of the screen. I would then like to save this screenshot to a database, prefferebly nsuserdefaults, since I am accessing it later in a table view. Any other suggestions on how to approach this, are more than welcome :)

The code is like this

```
let screenshot = getScreenshot() // saves the screenshot
var imagePaths = [String]()
// get the array of previous screenshots
if let _ = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey(theKey)
{
   imagePaths = NSUserDefaults.standardDefaults().objectForKey(theKey) as! [String]   
}
// then I want to get a path to the image something like
let imagePath = screenshot.getPath() // although this is not a valid method, this is basically what I want
// add the imagePath
imagePaths.append(imagePath)
// finally I save the image
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(imagePaths, forKey: theKey)
```

Comment: Do you want to store the actual image (NSData) or the path to the image (NSString) to the user defaults?

Comment: this does not really matter, all I need to do is display the image later, s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create directory in `Documents` and save there screenshots as usual files. Filename can be generated from date and time for uniqueness.

```
func saveImage(imageData: NSData)
{
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy hh.mm.ss"
    let filename = "\(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())).png"

    let documentsDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true).first as! String
    let imagesDirectory = documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("Images")
    let filePath = imagesDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent(filename)

    if !NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(imagesDirectory)
    {
        var error: NSError?

        NSFileManager.defaultManager().createDirectoryAtPath(imagesDirectory, withIntermediateDirectories: false, attributes: nil, error: &error)

        if error != nil
        {
            println("\(error!.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }
    }

    imageData.writeToFile(filePath, atomically: true)
}

func getImagesPaths() -> [String]?
{
    let documentsDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true).first as! String
    let imagesDirectory = documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("Images")

    if let filenames = NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(imagesDirectory, error: nil)
    {
        let imagePaths = filenames.map{"\(imagesDirectory)/\($0)"}.filter(){$0.pathExtension == "png"}
        return imagePaths.count > 0 ? imagePaths : nil
    }
    return nil
}
```

To save image simply use `saveImage(data)`. To get images paths use `getImagesPaths()`.

If you need array of `UIImage`, you can get it by follow way:

```
var images : [UIImage] = [ ]
if let imagePaths = getImagesPaths()
{
    for path in imagePaths
    {
        if let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: path)
        {
            images.append(image)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this and everything worked fine, except that when I closed the application, and tried to see if the saved image was still there, I got a nilpointerexception, here is how I tried to access the image `if let _ = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey(haikuKey)
        {
            let rawData = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey(haikuKey) as! [String]
            for rawImageData in rawData
            {
                images.append(UIImage(named: rawImageData)!)
            }
        }  `

Comment: The above code doesn't store the image data in the user defaults but only the paths to the image files. You need to initialize your UIImages with the data loaded from these paths.

Comment: And how would i go about doing this?

Comment: @DavidWolters `if let imagesPaths = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey(haikuKey) as? [String] { for path in imagesPaths { images.append(UIImage(contentsOfFile: path)) } }`

Comment: i get an error `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb) ` I directly copied your code

Comment: @DavidWolters It is possible that file does not exist with saved path. Path to `Documents` directory could change, if you are testing this on the simulator. In real case files can also deleted or moved. I think that it is better do not store file paths in `NSUserDefaults` and get them from the images directory. Or check for file existence before initiating `UIImage`.

Comment: I am a bit confused on how I would do that, could you explain further?

Comment: If I wanted to delete one of these images, how would I do that?

Comment: @DavidWolters If you want to delete a specific image, in this case, you need associate the image with its path. The easiest way - using Dictionary. [Sample code](http://pastebin.com/WNMvwiXV).